# Twisted factory protocol instance based callback

Tags: python, twisted, factory

Hey, I got a `ReconnectingClientFactory` and I wonder if I can somehow define protocol-instance-based `connectionMade`/`connectionLost` callbacks so that i can use the factory to connect to different hosts ans distinguish between each connection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No. Write a class that does the interaction with one user. In `connectionMade` you check if a instance of this class already exists, if not you make a new one and store it on the factory, ie in a `{ addr : handler }` dict. If the connection exists alreay you get the old handler from the factory.